# How to tell if a Flutter fix is available in a stable release?

Tags: flutter

I was looking at a specific bug for Flutter that looks to be closed now (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3795). Is there a way to say if the fix made it on a stable release?

Thanks,
Mihai

Comment: That was fixed in 2016, so: yes, for sure, it's in stable.

Comment: thanks @RichardHeap, but for other fixes how can you know if they made it in the sable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, the bug has a related PR. In the case of your example, the issue is related to [this PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/3797).

If the PR is merged, I usually check the merged commit (**40152c5**).
[image]

This commit will show in which tags it is already present. In this case, it was fixed since the **v0.0.6**
[image]

Then you just need to check the version that contains the fix and update your flutter version if needed.

Comment: Trying to follow your suggestion, I'm seeing "this commit does not belong to any branch on this repository." instead of the tags. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @syonip  what commit are you talking about? That's odd

Comment: Clicking on the link in your answer -> clicking "Commits" -> clicking on the first one -> Fixes #3795
 This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository.

Comment: @syonip wow, that's unexpected. For some reason, it's happening in every pull request in some big repositories. I am not really sure what's going on.